# File.setTitle method equivalent in Google Drive API v3

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Here is an [official example](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/drive-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/drive/cmdline/DriveSample.java):

```
package com.google.api.services.samples.drive.cmdline;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * A sample application that runs multiple requests against the Drive API. The requests this sample
 * makes are:
 * <ul>
 * <li>Does a resumable media upload</li>
 * <li>Updates the uploaded file by renaming it</li>
 * <li>Does a resumable media download</li>
 * <li>Does a direct media upload</li>
 * <li>Does a direct media download</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * @author rmistry@google.com (Ravi Mistry)
 */
public class DriveSample {

  /**
   * Be sure to specify the name of your application. If the application name is {@code null} or
   * blank, the application will log a warning. Suggested format is "MyCompany-ProductName/1.0".
   */
  private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "";

  private static final String UPLOAD_FILE_PATH = "Enter File Path";
  private static final String DIR_FOR_DOWNLOADS = "Enter Download Directory";
  private static final java.io.File UPLOAD_FILE = new java.io.File(UPLOAD_FILE_PATH);

  /** Directory to store user credentials. */
  private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
      new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/drive_sample");

  /**
   * Global instance of the {@link DataStoreFactory}. The best practice is to make it a single
   * globally shared instance across your application.
   */
  private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

  /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
  private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

  /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

  /** Global Drive API client. */
  private static Drive drive;

  /** Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data. */
  private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
    // load client secrets
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
        new InputStreamReader(DriveSample.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));
    if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
        || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
      System.out.println(
          "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=drive "
          + "into drive-cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    // set up authorization code flow
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
        Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE)).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
        .build();
    // authorize
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(
        !UPLOAD_FILE_PATH.startsWith("Enter ") && !DIR_FOR_DOWNLOADS.startsWith("Enter "),
        "Please enter the upload file path and download directory in %s", DriveSample.class);

    try {
      httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
      dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
      // authorization
      Credential credential = authorize();
      // set up the global Drive instance
      drive = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
          APPLICATION_NAME).build();

      // run commands

      View.header1("Starting Resumable Media Upload");
      File uploadedFile = uploadFile(false);

      View.header1("Updating Uploaded File Name");
      File updatedFile = updateFileWithTestSuffix(uploadedFile.getId());

      View.header1("Starting Resumable Media Download");
      downloadFile(false, updatedFile);

      View.header1("Starting Simple Media Upload");
      uploadedFile = uploadFile(true);

      View.header1("Starting Simple Media Download");
      downloadFile(true, uploadedFile);

      View.header1("Success!");
      return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(1);
  }

  /** Uploads a file using either resumable or direct media upload. */
  private static File uploadFile(boolean useDirectUpload) throws IOException {
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setTitle(UPLOAD_FILE.getName());

    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", UPLOAD_FILE);

    Drive.Files.Insert insert = drive.files().insert(fileMetadata, mediaContent);
    MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
    uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(useDirectUpload);
    uploader.setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener());
    return insert.execute();
  }

  /** Updates the name of the uploaded file to have a "drivetest-" prefix. */
  private static File updateFileWithTestSuffix(String id) throws IOException {
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setTitle("drivetest-" + UPLOAD_FILE.getName());

    Drive.Files.Update update = drive.files().update(id, fileMetadata);
    return update.execute();
  }

  /** Downloads a file using either resumable or direct media download. */
  private static void downloadFile(boolean useDirectDownload, File uploadedFile)
      throws IOException {
    // create parent directory (if necessary)
    java.io.File parentDir = new java.io.File(DIR_FOR_DOWNLOADS);
    if (!parentDir.exists() && !parentDir.mkdirs()) {
      throw new IOException("Unable to create parent directory");
    }
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(parentDir, uploadedFile.getTitle()));

    MediaHttpDownloader downloader =
        new MediaHttpDownloader(httpTransport, drive.getRequestFactory().getInitializer());
    downloader.setDirectDownloadEnabled(useDirectDownload);
    downloader.setProgressListener(new FileDownloadProgressListener());
    downloader.download(new GenericUrl(uploadedFile.getDownloadUrl()), out);
  }
}
```

One problem is that the `setTitle` method does not exist any more in the latest Java API. How do I set the title of a file now?

Answer (score 9):

Some changes in above code

- `setTitle` has been changed into `setName`
- Drive.Files.`Insert` ->  Drive.Files.`Create`
- drive.files().`insert`(fileMetadata, mediaContent); -> drive.files().`create`(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
- `getTitle()` -> `getName()`
- uploadedFile.`getDownloadUrl()` -> uploadedFile.`getWebViewLink()`

Following code has all new Method names.

change last part of code and paste

```
    private static File uploadFile(boolean useDirectUpload) throws IOException {
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setName(UPLOAD_FILE.getName());

    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", UPLOAD_FILE);

    Drive.Files.Create insert = drive.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent);
    MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
    uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(useDirectUpload);
    uploader.setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener());
    return insert.execute();
  }

  /** Updates the name of the uploaded file to have a "drivetest-" prefix. */
  private static File updateFileWithTestSuffix(String id) throws IOException {
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setName("drivetest-" + UPLOAD_FILE.getName());

    Drive.Files.Update update = drive.files().update(id, fileMetadata);
    return update.execute();
  }

  /** Downloads a file using either resumable or direct media download. */
  private static void downloadFile(boolean useDirectDownload, File uploadedFile)
      throws IOException {
    // create parent directory (if necessary)
    java.io.File parentDir = new java.io.File(DIR_FOR_DOWNLOADS);
    if (!parentDir.exists() && !parentDir.mkdirs()) {
      throw new IOException("Unable to create parent directory");
    }
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(parentDir, uploadedFile.getName()));

    MediaHttpDownloader downloader =
        new MediaHttpDownloader(httpTransport, drive.getRequestFactory().getInitializer());
    downloader.setDirectDownloadEnabled(useDirectDownload);
    downloader.setProgressListener(new FileDownloadProgressListener());
    downloader.download(new GenericUrl(uploadedFile.getWebViewLink()), out);
  }
```

Comment: it is multipath upload?,And I think MediaHttpUploader is deprecated in google drive API v3. I it is good to use  MediaHttpUploader in drive API v3 to show uploading progrees in andorid.

Comment: @NathaniSoftware no its not multipath. Not aware about mediahttpuploader

Answer (score 2):

`setTitle` has been changed into `setName` in v3.